# What is the POSTCSS equivalent for the Ampersand(&) commonly used in LESS, SASS and STYLUS?

Tags: sass, less, postcss

So with less I could do `&` to do a combination.

eg:

```
.baa {
  &.foo {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

which would generate a rule `.baa.foo`

What plugins and syntax do we need for postcss to do the same thing?

Answer (score 8):

For posterity,

we need this postcss plugin:

https://github.com/postcss/postcss-nested